# Ruby/Rails - kaminari undefined method pagination errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, kaminari

I'm not sure what I did, but kaminari has started acting weird in my app.

In my controller:

```
@producers = Producer.order(:name).page(params[:page])
```

view:

```
<%= paginate @producers %>
```

results in:

```
undefined method `num_pages' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x000001026e6308>
```

If I add .per in my controller:

```
@producers = Producer.order(:name).page(params[:page]).per(25)
```

I get

```
undefined local variable or method `per' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x0000010928ef60>
```

Finally, strangely, if I move my `.order(:name)` to the end, it works:

```
@producers = Producer.page(params[:page]).order(:name)
```

I'm guessing some other gem I have installed has a `page` scope or method that's causing problems?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, just figured it out.
I had [Active Admin](http://activeadmin.info/) installed.  It installed `will_paginate` as a dependency.

In the latest commits for `Active Admin`, `will_paginate` has been replaced with `kaminari`.

I changed my Gemfile to pull `Active Admin` from github. `will_paginate` was removed from my bundle and now everything works. You can do this by putting the following line into your gemfile:

```
gem "activeadmin", git: "https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin"
```

Comment: how did you pull 'Active Admin' from github?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with another gem that required will_paginate. The issue was resolved with this code snippet which was taken from active_admin [wiki](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/wiki/How-to-work-with-will_paginate) page:

```
if defined?(WillPaginate)
  module WillPaginate
    module ActiveRecord
      module RelationMethods
        def per(value = nil) per_page(value) end
        def total_count() count end
      end
    end
    module CollectionMethods
      alias_method :num_pages, :total_pages
    end
  end
end
```

Put it in an initializer.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem, include `gem 'kaminari'` and remove `will_paginate`. Since I have already been using `will_paginate`, I just updated my current will_paginate calls to kaminari. They are very similar to implement and easy enough to change.

Answer (score 0):

I tried johnnycakes's solution, but it kept giving me stack level too deep errors on the dashboard (similar to https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/157)

The solution I found was to specify this revision:

```
gem 'activeadmin', :git => 'git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git', :ref => '811f286fda3b6dfa91aa'
```