# Kaminari & Rails pagination - undefined method `num_pages'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

Here's my controller:

```
def show        
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.page(params[:page])
end
```

This is working fine if I dont add following code to show.html.erb:

```
<%= paginate @microposts %>
```

Its giving following error:

```
undefined method `num_pages' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fc2ca54b228>
```

How can I fix this? Using Rails 3.2.8 & Kaminari 0.13.0

Comment: Is there any chance that you're using active admin? If yes, than this could apply to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919082/ruby-rails-kaminari-undefined-method-pagination-errors

Comment: no i am not using active admin simple pagination with kaminari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got my answer. I had google it and found that kaminari has some issue with will_paginate so i had run following command to uninstall will_paginate

```
gem uninstall will_paginate
```

Also restart the rails server and now its working fine.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: These two gems are generally incompatible, though there is a way to get them to coexist:

See the last code block on this article: http://belighted.com/en/blog/will_paginate-vs-kaminari

For the record, I think you should just choose one or the other, rather than monkey-patching them to coexist in this way.

Comment: I think your down vote of my answers was a bit harsh, considering you didn't mention you even had will_paginate installed